# Setting Clipboard from non-ui thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-activity, clipboard

---

### Issue: Can't set clipboard from non-ui background thread

---

How would I go around setting the clipboard while my app is in the background?

```
public class Messages {

    public void SetMessage(String text) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
            clipboard.setText(text);
        } else {
            android.content.ClipboardManager clipboard = (android.content.ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
            ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("NewClip", text);
                            clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
        }
    }
}
```

*Error: Cannot resolve getSystemService(java.lang.String)*

---

### I tried multiple things to solve this issue, one of them is:

---

#### Configuration Class

```
/* I made a Config class file like so: */
public final class Config {
    public static com.dysanix.official.MainActivity MainContext = null;
}


/* And put this in the onCreate of the MainActivity: */
Config.MainContext = this;


/*
 * And then using Config.MainContext.getSystemService() in the other
 * class works, as long as the UI is visible on the screen.. but as soon as
 * I tab out, the code doesn't work anymore.
 */
```

*I also tried making a "Runnable" in the MainActivity and call that from another class, but the same issue: It works, until I tab out of the App. I am calling the method from a looped AsyncTask, which I know works because the console keeps printing a Log message at the end of the loop.*

**Any help would be greatly appreciated!**

Comment: Don't keep tasks running when your activity stopped, use a service when something needs to run longer than the activity and tie the background task's life to that of the service. That's what they are for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Error: Cannot resolve getSystemService(java.lang.String)

`getSystemService()` is a method on `Context`. Pass a `Context` into your `SetMessage()` method, or move that method to some `Activity`, `Service`, or other `Context` implementation. Then, call `getSystemService()` on that `Context`.

> I tried multiple things to solve this issue, one of them is:

Do not put an `Activity` in a static field. Not only will that represent a memory leak, but the `Activity` is useless once it is destroyed, anyway.

> Issue: Can't set clipboard from non-ui background thread

There is nothing related to threads here.

Comment: Okay so I made a service that is running now, and to prove it I added a TextView to it with "Running". It is overlapping other chats. (I used this site: http://myandroidtuts.blogspot.nl/2013/05/facebook-chat-heads-feature.html) Now how would I add this clipboard method to that service and call it from a random non-ui class?

Comment: @DysanixOfficial: Most likely, you would not call it from a "random class". Whatever that "random class" is needs access to a `Context`.

Comment: Okay, so I have the service, and I have a "Messages.class" file. That messages class file looks like this: `public class Messages {
    public static void SetMessage(Context context, String text){
        MainService.SetMessage(context, text);
    }
}` Now what would the context be if I want to call Messages.SentMessage() from any class I want?

Comment: @DysanixOfficial: You do not call `SentMessage()` "from any class [you] want". You either call it from a `Context` (e.g., your activity or service, so you can pass `this` as the `Context`), or you call it from some object that itself has a `Context`.

Comment: Ooooh! I get it now! I am so sorry, now I read myself back I look really dumb, but I was thinking in a strange way. Thanks for you answer! I actually understand it now!